# Can you use PhoneGap on Ubuntu to develop iPhone apps?

Tags: application-development, development, iphone

I heard about PhoneGap which let's you develop Android and iPhone apps,
and it compiles it from HTML/CSS/JS.

I have only one PC with Ubuntu installed,
and I want to make a mobile App from HTML/CSS/JS code so it sounds perfect.

What I wonder about if it's also possible to compile the iPhone apps with it 
even if I don't have a Mac,
and though this is not a legal forum, I know Apple have some harsh laws regarding that stuff.

It's probably possible for me to have access to an Apple computer for a couple of hours to register to Apple and upload the App.

But I don't have a Mac to do the development on.

So is this possible?

Comment: See detailed answer on SO.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Setting Up An Android App Build Environment With Eclipse, Android SDK,
>   PhoneGap.  The tutorial describes how you can set up a development
>   environment for building Android apps on an Ubuntu 10.10 desktop using
>   Eclipse, the Android SDK, and PhoneGap.
>
> But first you have to do the following:  Installing Eclipse And
>   Prerequisites For The Android SDK/PhoneGap
>
> Eclipse and the prerequisites for the Android SDK and PhoneGap can be
>   installed as follows:<sup>1</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk eclipse ruby rubygems ruby-dev git ant libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Next run

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

> Then you need to install the Android SDK.  Go to
>   [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). There you will find links for the Android
>   SDK.<sup>1</sup>

[Read on](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-an-android-app-build-environment-with-eclipse-android-sdk-phonegap-ubuntu-10.10)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Setting Up An Android App Build Environment With Eclipse, Android SDK, PhoneGap](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-an-android-app-build-environment-with-eclipse-android-sdk-phonegap-ubuntu-10.10)</sup>

**Can I build for iPhone?
Yes! Check out our iOS Guide for information on how to get PhoneGap Build up and running with iOS.**<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[PhoneGap](https://build.phonegap.com/faq)</sup>